# Alternatives to Pyttsx for TTS?

Tags: python, python-3.x, text-to-speech, python-module, pyttsx

I have tried using Pyttsx for Text-To-Speech with Python 3 in the past. However, the voice sounds very crude and isn't as life-like as other Text-To-Speech services such as Google Assistant. Are there any other ready out-of-the-box Text-To-Speech modules for Python 3?